# How to synchronize multiple FileSystemWatchers (Windows, C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystemwatcher

I'm using multiple instances of FileSystemWatcher to monitor multiple directories.

All of them are paired with the same OnChanged method in which I call some of my methods.

The problem is, when there are many changes at a time, sometimes multiple FileSystemWatchers are firing OnChanged at the same time, causing my application to freeze.

How can I synchronize them so only one instance of FileSystemWatcher at a time can have access to OnChanged method? I.e I want to block all access to OnChanged until one FileSystemWatcher is finished with it.

I would appreciate if someone could give example of code.

Comment: Blocking the FSW events is a bad idea.  Use a thread-safe queue.

Comment: What Hans said, because what to say you want will not work.

Comment: You mean I should store all the notifications in the queue and deal with them later? Is there any template of such thread safe queue in WinAPI?

Comment: Google 'Windows producer-consumer queue'.  You could use a Windows Message Queue - it's slow, and only allows one consumer to wait, but it'll probably do for your purpose.